# jobject returned by JNI isn't setting fields

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I use JNI to set some fields as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
jclass complexClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, thisObj);
jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, complexClass, "exampleVar", "I");
jint secondnumber = 30;
(*env)->SetIntField(env, complexClass, fid, secondnumber);
}
```

But after setting the int field, when I read it back where I made the first call from, the value isn't modified. I tried providing both setter as well as made the field "exampleVar" public but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You sure everything initializing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a non-static field, you need to provide the object to `SetIntField()`, not the class.

Your lack of error checking has concealed this.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that.
 (*env)->SetIntField(env, thisObj, fid, secondnumber); works